# I want to scroll to a specific location Selenium Java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2

I have a list of webelements, I have written the below code:

```
    List <WebElement> feature_tiles = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'featuretile')]//a"));
    System.out.println("" +feature_tiles.size() );
    
    for(int i=0; i<feature_tiles.size();i++)
    {
        double x = feature_tiles.get(i).getLocation().getX();
        double y = feature_tiles.get(i).getLocation().getY();
        
        JavascriptExecutor javScriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        javScriptExecutor.executeScript("window.scrollBy(" + x + ", " + y + ");")
        
    }
```

what I want to do is, scroll to that particular element and wait for it to load and also take a screen shot, of the individual elemetns.

Current is scrolling to the elements even if the images of the elements is not loaded correctly.

Comment: Welcome. So far, it seems it's working correctly. Selenium will scroll to any x,y location regardless if an element is there or not. Right now, your code doesn't show any waits or screenshot. So, if you want it to wait after the scroll, you'll need to add that. If you do have that, please update your example.

Comment: which website please add more details

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("mousehover"));
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, -190);");
```

For Screenshot, you have to use TakeScreenshot

```
File sourceFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, new File(directory + filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is faced by most of the software testing service companies to verify elements visually through automation.
In this case instead of taking complete screenshot they prefer to have desired webelement screenshot.
In C# we use 'Ashot' library by which we can capture screenshot of complete webpage by scrolling to bottom of the page if available or we can have screenshot for webElement also.

Refer below syntax for webelement capturing:

Screenshot screenshot = new AShot()
.takeScreenshot(driver, webelement);
ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(), "PNG", new File("{location of the screenshot to be saved}"));